# get value of select option in multiple row

Tags: javascript, php, html

My php code is as follows

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["pitcode"]))
    {
        echo $_POST['pitcode'];
        $pnetamt=0;
        foreach ($_POST['txtwono1'] as $k => $v) 
        {
            $pitcode=$_POST['pitcode'][$k];
            $m_no=0;
            $sql = mysql_query("select itrate from ITMAST where itcode='$pitcode'") or die(mysql_error());
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            $m_no = mysql_num_rows($sql);
            if ($m_no!=0)
            {
                $sql = mysql_query("select itrate from ITMAST where itcode='$pitcode'") or die(mysql_error());
                $row = mysql_fetch_row($sql);
                $prate=$row[0];
            }

        }
    }
?>
```

Javascript code is

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      function getitemcode()
      {
      var model=$('#itname').val();
      document.frmwo.getElementById("txtitcode").value = model;
      }
</script>
```

and HTML is

```
<html>
   <td><input type="text" maxlength="3" size="2" name="txtwono1[]" class="rightJustified" value="<?php echo $pwono1; ?>"/></td>
   <td><input type="text" maxlength="2" size="2" name="txtsno[]" class="rightJustified" value="<?php echo $psno; ?>"/></td>
   <td>
       <?php
            $sql = "SELECT itcode,itname FROM ITMAST ";
            $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
            echo "<select name='itname[]' id='itname' onchange='getitemcode()'>";
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
                {
                    echo "<option value = '{$row['itcode']}'";
                        if ($pitcode == $row['itcode'])
                            echo "selected = 'selected'";
                    echo ">{$row['itname']}</option>";
                }
                echo "</select>";
        ?>
   </td>
   <td><input type="text" maxlength="8" size="8" name="txtitcode" id='txtitcode' class="rightJustified"  value="<?php echo $pitcode; ?>"/></td>
   <td><input type="text" maxlength="8" size="8" name="txtqty[]" class="rightJustified" onchange="calcitemamt()" value="<?php echo $pqty; ?>"/></td>
   <td><input type="text" maxlength="6" size="6" name="txtrate[]" class="rightJustified" disabled="disabled" value="<?php echo $prate; ?>"/></td>
   <td><input type="text" maxlength="7" size="7" name="txtamt[]"  disabled="disabled" class="rightJustified" value="<?php echo $pamt; ?>"/></td>
</html>
```

My Problem is when I selects the Item from Combo, its value is not passed to php code from where I am getting price of that item and that price should come to in rate column. This should work for all rows of html table - How

Comment: what is frmwo in document.frmwo.getElementById in your code??

Comment: Use if (isset($_POST["itemname"])) rather than if (isset($_POST["pitcode"]))

Comment: yes used now $_POST['itname'], How I can get current row no and how to assign value to rate column which is 4th and my current row is say 3 out of 7 rows, first to find current row, then assign value from php code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change html code

```
echo "<select name='itname[]' id='itname' onchange='getitemcode()'>";
```

with

```
echo "<select name='itname[]' id='itname' onchange='getitemcode(this.value)'>";
```

also change javascript code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      function getitemcode()
      {
      var model=$('#itname').val();
      document.frmwo.getElementById("txtitcode").value = model;
      }
</script>
```

with

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
      function getitemcode(model)
      {

      document.frmwo.getElementById("txtitcode").value = model;
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not still working, I made changes as above

Comment: I made change from document.frmwo.getElementById("txtitcode").value = model; to document.getElementById("txtitcode").value = model; now it is working but values from second rows are also coming to first row